# How do I create a floating toolbar in swing?

Tags: java, swing

I have a JComponent that I draw on using openGL.  It is enclosed in a panel with some side panels and a jmenu. It is getting cramped so I want to make the next set of controls into a window the user can show/hide/move around.

How do I make an option in my JMENU that when I click it a window is spawned that resides in my application as if  that will reside within my  jframe but be draggable, non modal, closable, always on top?

When I minimize my app or my app loses focus it should not be visible.

Essentially, I want a toolbar that the user can show/hide/move themselves.

Comment: I dont have any experience with this but I found two links that may help you. Check this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366772/draggable-toolbar.

Comment: @amb110395 Thanks for the links, I am able to set up a draggable toolbar but I cannot seem to find a way to float it using code. I am trying jdialog but I am concerned that jdialog may be a problem as this window will always be open.

Comment: @dah Go here: www.java2s.com › Java › Swing JFC › Toolbar‎

Comment: @dah What do you mean by float it? Does the JToolBar not detach for you?

Comment: `JToolBar` is a good choice; please specify your Gl library; see also [*Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Comment: @sdasdadas I want the toolbar to float immediately, instead of needing to drag it. I also want it to be undockable.

Comment: @Sajjad Thanks, I have checked it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a [draggabletoolbar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) object.

See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366772/draggable-toolbar.) for example implementation.